# In Laravel 9, when I run "php artisan route:list" I get this error " ReflectionException Class "PostsController" does not exist"

Tags: php, laravel

I made a controller by running:

```
php artisan make:controller PostsController
```

And then I put this inside my web.php

```
Route::controller(PostsController::class)->group(function () {
 Route::get('/posts', 'index');
 Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'show');
 Route::post('/posts', 'store');
});
```

But when I run php artisan route:list I get the error. I have already run composer update and composer dump-autoload.

My laravel version is: Laravel Framework 9.36.4

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Maybe that controller uses a namespace, and your web.php does not import that yet?

Comment: Yep, according to other people, they made it work by running these: composer update and composer dump-autoload but on my end, it still won't work. In my controller, this is imported "namespace App\Http\Controllers;"

Comment: try using: `use App\Http\Controllers\PostsController;`

Comment: Yep, in web.php thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's working now, I had to import the controller inside the web.php
I thought that was automatic! Lol!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).